# Optimize Sass variables list

Tags: sass

I have this list of color variables:

```
//** Smoke
$smoke-hex-l-10: #504c51;
$smoke-hex-l-20: #575358;
$smoke-hex-l-25: #5b575c;
$smoke-hex-l-30: #5e5a60;
$smoke-hex-l-40: #656167;
$smoke-hex-l-50: #6d686e;
$smoke-hex-l-60: #746f76;
$smoke-hex-l-70: #7b767d;
$smoke-hex-l-75: #7f7981;
$smoke-hex-l-80: #827d84;
$smoke-hex-l-90: #89848b;
$smoke-hex-l-100: #908b92;

$smoke-hex-d-10: #423f43;
$smoke-hex-d-20: #3c3a3d;
$smoke-hex-d-25: #3a373b;
$smoke-hex-d-30: #383539;
$smoke-hex-d-40: #343135;
$smoke-hex-d-50: #302e31;
$smoke-hex-d-60: #2d2b2e;
$smoke-hex-d-70: #2b292b;
$smoke-hex-d-75: #29282a;
$smoke-hex-d-80: #282629;
$smoke-hex-d-90: #262427;
$smoke-hex-d-100: #242325
```

Is there a way to optimize this list in some way? I'm not very good a Sass, but I've read about Sass Maps, but I can't wrap my head around the concept.

Or if a list like that it's just the way to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use sass maps to store these variables, it may look like this:

```
//** Smoke
$smoke-hex-l: (
    10: #504c51,
    20: #575358,
    25: #5b575c,
    30: #5e5a60,
    40: #656167,
    50: #6d686e,
    60: #746f76,
    70: #7b767d,
    75: #7f7981,
    80: #827d84,
    90: #89848b,
    100: #908b92,
);

$smoke-hex-d: (
    10: #423f43,
    20: #3c3a3d,
    25: #3a373b,
    30: #383539,
    40: #343135,
    50: #302e31,
    60: #2d2b2e,
    70: #2b292b,
    75: #29282a,
    80: #282629,
    90: #262427,
    100: #24232,
);
```

and can be accessed like: `$smoke-color: map-get($smoke-hex-l, 10);`

However it looks like these colors are just lighten / darken versions of common base color, something like `#49464a`. In this case you can simplify your code by using color manipulation functions that are available in Sass. In particular [`lighten()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method) and [`darken()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) will be enough to replace whole set of colors that you have.

Comment: Ah! I see, I wasn't so far off :p. HUGE Thanks for providing the usage as well. Regarding the `lighten()`/`darken()` functions, you would think that would work (and that was actually my first approach) but it doesn't. Sass shoots out a completely different color (not CRAZY off though but different nonetheless) than what we require, so that method didn't work very well for us. Pretty frigging weird if you ask me. Thanks again!

Comment: @RicardoZea Your colors range does not completely straight, but you may tune it by applying additional colors manipulations. You can for example plot your colors in HSB color space to see how do they look like and re-implement this line of colors using color functions.

Comment: What do you mean the colors range isn't completely straight?

Comment: @RicardoZea Take a look at your colors (I've taken `$smoke-hex-d` as example) in different color spaces: `#504c51 = hsb(288,6,32) = lab(33,3,-2)`, `242325 = hsb(270,5,15) = lab(14,1,-1)`. As you can see - main changes are on `B` in HSB and `L` in Lab, it means that this color range mainly fades to darkness. However there are slight changes in hue and micro changes in saturation. While saturation changes can be ignored - hue changes are here and hence your color range can't be completely replaced by `lighten()` and `darken()` since results will be slightly different

Comment: My apologies, I'm not entirely following, sorry. Yes, some colors fade to darkness and white in the middle fractions (50-80) but that's because their lightness is already either quite high/low. If you could elaborate a bit that'd be great. Thank you.

Comment: @RicardoZea if your colors are chosen manually then it will be better to stay with color maps like they're listed in my answer. Additionally you can take a look at [mix()](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#mix-instance_method) function to get intermediate colors if necessary.

Comment: I'm blown away… How did I not know about the `mix()` function!? :O - It would've been SO MUCH easier to go that route than to have to deal with a list like the one I created. Thanks so much for the enlightening , hahaha.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that this information was helpful